# Incorporate more information about variables on axes into a heatmap in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to annotate a heat-map by putting symbols next to the axis text.

For instance, lets say I am plotting out a distance matrix. Here's an example of such a matrix for environmental community similarity:

```
library(vegan)
library(tidyverse)
data(varespec)
data(varechem)
library(reshape2)
library(viridis)

vare.dist <- vegdist(varespec)

vare.hc <- hclust(as.dist(vare.dist))

vare.dist.long <- vare.dist %>% as.matrix %>% melt %>%
mutate(Var1 = factor(Var1, levels = unique(vare.hc$labels)[vare.hc$order]))%>%
mutate(Var2 = factor(Var2, levels = unique(vare.hc$labels)[vare.hc$order]))

vare.dist.long %>% #as.matrix %>% .[vare.hc$order, vare.hc$order] %>% melt %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + scale_fill_viridis(direction = 1) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270, hjust = 0, vjust = 0.5
                                ))
```

[image: test heatmap]
*Figure 1. A heatmap of distances between different sites in the varespec data set.*

Let's say I want to indicate which sites have higher than average nitrogen, phosphorous and potassium. I want to indicate this data along the axis, reserving the y-axis for some other purpose. One ugly way of doing this would be to modify the text strings, and text font, for axis one.

```
## Define a few helper functions
transmit_factor_order <- function(ordered, unordered){
    # allows us to put a character vector or unordered factor in the same order as another factor
    # ordered is an ordered factor
    # unordered is an unordered factor or character vector

    if(class(ordered) != 'factor'){
        stop("'ordered' must be of class factor")
    }

    nrow = length(ordered)
    df = data.frame(ordered, unordered, oldorder = 1:nrow)

    df = df[order(df[,"ordered"]),]
    df[,"unordered"] = factor(df[,"unordered"], levels = unique(df[,"unordered"]))
    df = df[order(df[,"oldorder"]),]

    df$unordered
}

medcode_chr <- function(vec, low = "", high = "o"){
    # convert a vector of numbers into one of symbols (or numbers) with one value
    # for lower than median values and one for higher than median values
    sapply(vec, function(x){
    if(x < median(na.omit(vec))){low}else{high}
    }
           )
           }

## Actual Work
vare.dist.long %>%
     # convert numeric vector to character
mutate(Var1_chr = as.character(Var1)) %>%
     # append the envioronmental data
left_join(varechem %>% rownames_to_column %>% dplyr::select(rowname:K),
          by =  c('Var1_chr' = 'rowname')) %>%
     # make new columns with symbols that we display if values are bigger than the median
mutate(highN = medcode_chr(N),
       highP = medcode_chr(P, high = "+"),
       highK = medcode_chr(K, low = 0, high = 1)) %>%
     # make a new name, which is the number, appended to the symbols defined above
unite(Var1_Annotated, Var1, highN, highP, sep = " ", remove = FALSE) %>%
     # make sure that newly named vecotr is in the same order as Var1
     #(which was ordered for clustering purposes)
mutate(Var1_Annotated = transmit_factor_order(Var1, Var1_Annotated)) %>%
     # do the same thing to the character version of Var1, which will be useful downstream
mutate(Var1_chr = transmit_factor_order(Var1, Var1_chr))-> vare.data

vare.data %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = Var1_Annotated, y = Var2, fill = value)) + geom_tile() + scale_fill_viridis(direction = 1) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270, hjust = 0, vjust = 0.5, 
                                 face = ifelse(vare.data$highK, "bold", "plain"),
                                 colour = ifelse(vare.data$highK, "red", "blue")
                                ))
```

[image: ugly names]
*Figure 2. Another heatmap of distances between different sites in the varespec data set. This time the x-axis names have been modified to show if nitrogen is high or low (presence or absence of "o"), whether phosphorous is high or low (presence or abscence of "+"), and whether potassium is high (red) or low (blue).*

This figure conveys the information that I need, but it's kind of ugly. I'd rather say, place differently colored circles to convey which things have high nitrogen, phosphorous and potassium. I'm thinking something like the following, but actually part of the previous figure.

```
vare.data %>% dplyr::select(-c(Var2, value)) %>% unique %>% arrange(Var1_Annotated) %>%
mutate(highN = medcode_chr(N, 0, 1),
       highP = medcode_chr(P, 0, 1),
       highK = medcode_chr(K, 0, 1)) %>%
dplyr::select(-c(N,P,K, Var1, Var1_Annotated))  %>%
gather(key, value, -Var1_chr) %>% 
filter(value == 1) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Var1_chr, y = key, color = key)) + geom_point() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270, hjust = 0, vjust = 0.5),
     axis.text.y = element_blank(),
     axis.title.y = element_blank(),
     axis.title.x = element_blank()) + 
coord_fixed(ratio = 0.3)
```

[image: dotslegend]
*Figure 3. Colored points, that I'd like to incorperate into Figure 1 to make it prettier than figure 2 but convey the same information.*

Is there some way I can incorporate the colored dots (Figure 3) into the heatmap (Figure 1) so I can show the data about how the sites cluster and concurrently tell information about the different sites, as I do in Figure 2?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (rather dirty) option would be to arrange both grobs, align them by vertically, tinker with the grobs vertical position, andedit the x-axis' scales and titles.

```
library(cowplot)
A <- vare.dist.long %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, fill = value)) +
     geom_tile() + 
     scale_fill_viridis(direction = 1) +
     theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
           axis.title.x = element_blank(),
           plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,-1.5,1), "cm") ## Note the -1.5, it tells the grob to print itself 1.5 cm below its normal position.
           ) #/theme

B <- vare.data %>% dplyr::select(-c(Var2, value)) %>% unique %>% 
     arrange(Var1_Annotated) %>%
     mutate(highN = medcode_chr(N, 0, 1),
            highP = medcode_chr(P, 0, 1),
            highK = medcode_chr(K, 0, 1)) %>%
     dplyr::select(-c(N,P,K, Var1, Var1_Annotated))  %>%
     gather(key, value, -Var1_chr) %>% 
     filter(value == 1) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = Var1_chr, y = key, color = key)) + 
       geom_point() +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 270, hjust = 0, vjust = 0.5),
             axis.text.y = element_blank(),
             axis.title.y = element_blank(),
             plot.margin = unit(c(0,1,1,1), "cm")) +
     coord_fixed(ratio = 0.3)

cowplot::plot_grid(A,B, nrow = 2, align = "v")
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. I notice that the tick marks are still a tiny bit misaligned. For instance 15 in the B panel falls halfway between two tick marks on the top plot. I initially presumed that I could monkey with the plot margins of A and B but while changing the top and botom margins seems to move the two elements relative to each other, changing the right and left ones seems to either make both plots the same amount thinner (if positive), or has no effect (if negative). Is there some way around this?

Comment: Indeed, this is a dirty approach. But there are at least 3 different things that affect the alignment that you can control to some degree. The first one, is the number of axis breaks. In this particular case, the heatmap has 24 breaks, while the scatterplot has only 23. This is a result of the data frames structures you provided us. If you make sure that the scatter plot gets its 24th category, then the misalignment will be corrected.

Comment: The second one is the space taken by the x and y axis' titles and breaks. This is common when a title has more than one line, as when it includes linebreaks or carriage returns (\n\r).
The third one, much less common, is the size of the legends. Sometimes a workaround is to palce the legends on the top or the bottom of the plots.

Comment: Great point with your observation that the scatterplot has only 23 points. I offer an edit to your solution that should correct for this oversight on my part.

Comment: @ohnoplus please, reserve edits for corrections only, not to include content you create (as this is a non-wiki answer). To leave feedback inform answerer and led him do the edits instead. That or answer your own question instead

Comment: Fine. I'll try to replicate what my edit said in the comments. I dont' think it warrents writing a different answer since @NicolásVelásquez was correct in answering my question. If one wants to get the tick marks to match up (1) comment out the filter line. (2) add `alpha = factor(value)` to the ggplot(aes(...)) part under B (3) add `+ scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0,1)`